# Shadow has very low effect

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview, uikit

I can't work out why a shadow from a UIView has such a low effect even though it has such high opacity and a large radius.

I tried adding a shadow to two different views, one of the views(Base View) is on the same layer as the UIImageView(Top Img View) and the other view(Shadow View) is on the layer above the UIImageView(Top Img View).

[image: Image of what I've described above]

Here is my code for adding the shadows on to Base View. Note, I used the exact same code when attempting to add a shadow on Shadow View I just replaced baseView with shadowView.

```
baseView.clipsToBounds = false
baseView.layer.masksToBounds = false

baseView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
baseView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
baseView.layer.shadowRadius = 280
```

The shadow is cast although it's very subtle. Below is an image of the shadow being cast with using the code above.

[image: Shadow Added]

I have also tried some small tweaks such as adding this code to the imageView.

```
topImgView.clipsToBounds = false
topImgView.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

But it didn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: you uploaded or at least referenced the same image twice.

Comment: You could use a image with shadow content to replace the shadow effect.

Comment: Fixed the image issue. I'm not sure how the shadow would work on the image because I'd somehow need to invert the shadow so it came up onto the image.

Comment: How does the shadow look if you change `.shadowRadius` from `280` to `8` or `12` or `16`?

Comment: The shadow does look a lot more visible but ideally I would like that visibility in conjunction with a larger radius. Although, i'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: @JohnJones - show an image of how you want it to look.

Comment: I ended up using a gradient instead because it produced a much greater effect.